# Get drive letter/host install location of MSYS from terminal or Qmake?

Tags: qmake, msys

I have a QT Qmake project which has a lot of blocks like this for MSYS compatibility:

```
# VTK
win32 {
  INCLUDEPATH += c:/msys64/mingw64/include/vtk-$${VTKVERSION}
  LIBS += -Lc:/msys64/mingw64/lib
}
else {
  INCLUDEPATH += $$VTKINCPATH
  LIBS += -L$$VTKLIBPATH
}
```

This has worked fine up until now, but now I have a problem. Due to limited space, I have installed MSYS on an external D drive, which breaks all of these such include types.

Is there a programmatic way using either QMake or a command from within MSYS2 to get the drive letter that MSYS is currently installed in?

Maybe I could stitch it together if PACMAN offers a drive path. If I try putting in the package name with -Ql, it just gives me the path relative to MSYS root, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

The tool [cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) can do this.

The command I use is:

`cygpath -m /`

Which in my case will print out:

`D:/msys64/`